# Ionic2 accesing variables in nested methods of cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, angular, cordova-plugins, ibeacon, ionic2

I am developing mobile app with ionic2(beta 8,Cordova 6.2) latest and facing issue to accessing variable in cordova mehtod(Functions).My code is like

```
import {Page, NavController, Alert, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import {StatusBar,cordovaBeacon} from 'ionic-native'; 
import {AuthService} from '../home/authservice'; 
import {HomePage} from '../home/home';


export class UserPage {
    constructor(authservice, navcontroller) {
        this.service = authservice;
        this.nav = navcontroller;
        this.distance = 0;    
    }

    getDistance(){               
       this.distance=-50;//This is working and change view perfactly

       var delegate = new cordova.plugins.locationManager.Delegate();

       delegate.didRangeBeaconsInRegion = function (pluginResult) {
           //I got reading of beacons but can't access distance variable to change distance in associate view
           this.distance=pluginResult.beacons[0].rssi;
           /*This wan't work, can't access this.distance variable         to update(View) proximity of ibeacon in delegete method*/
       }; 

       var uuid = '33333333-3333-4444-5555-666666666666 ';
       var identifier = 'BEacon 2';
       var minor = '1';
       var major = '1';

       var beaconRegion = new cordova.plugins.locationManager.BeaconRegion(identifier, uuid, major, minor);

      cordova.plugins.locationManager.setDelegate(delegate);
      cordova.plugins.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();
      cordova.plugins.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization();

      cordova.plugins.locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion)
          .fail(function(e) { console.error(e); })
          .done();
    }
 }
```

Using this plugin for beacon detection
1) https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon/

So Questions are

1. **Any global variable for ionic2 that can accessible anywhere?**
2. **Any other workaround of above given issue?**

Please Advice
-Naitik

Comment: Use promises instead of delegates. I might be missing something but there is nothing that calls didRangeBeaconInRegion. You only delegated not activated

Comment: Can you please give me code snippet because i'm new to angular2 and ionic2! Please.

Comment: where are you importing the plugin? can you show your imports as well thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use arrow notation you will maintain `this` context:

```
constructor(authservice, navcontroller, ngzone) {...}

 delegate.didRangeBeaconsInRegion = (pluginResult) => {
           this.ngzone.run( () => {
               this.distance=pluginResult.beacons[0].rssi;           
           });
       };
```

**Edit:**

Additionally, since this will run outside the angular zone, you need to wrap it within an angular ngZone.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your help but it did not update associated view value?

Like

Meters: {{distance}}

or

< ion-range [(ngModel)]="distance" danger pin="true">

Please help.

Comment: look at the edit, you need to import ngzone and inject it in the constructor